# What is the name of this cognitive bias?

Tags: fallacies, cognitive-bias

When it comes to plane crashes, the statistical chance of getting into one is extremely low, however, due to the media making so much content about plane crashes, people assume they are much more likely to get into a crash than they actually are.

Similarly: the only news that comes out regarding doctors is when some doctor gets caught committing a crime, and thus the common man gets a skewed opinion regarding all doctors, even when the vast majority works honestly.

**What is the name of this cognitive bias?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer

These are examples of the cognitive bias known as the [availability heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic).

#### Long Answer

What stands out immediately is your two references to the media and our exposure to their content. According to WP:

> The availability heuristic, also known as availability bias, is a mental shortcut that relies on immediate examples that come to a given person's mind when evaluating a specific topic, concept, method or decision. The availability heuristic operates on the notion that if something can be recalled, it must be important, or at least more important than alternative solutions which are not as readily recalled.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic) Subsequently, under the availability heuristic, people tend to heavily weigh their judgments toward more recent information, making new opinions biased toward that latest news.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Better_Angels_of_Our_Nature)

It's no secret that we can get a false picture of the world, particularly because human beings have brains that have not evolved as statistical computers. Given this poor intuition, we can be deceived. Today, many people on earth are convinced that the world is [going to hell in a handbasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_hell_in_a_handbasket) despite the fact that science and statistics assure us the world is the safest, most productive, and most peaceful it has ever been, a thesis championed by [Steven Pinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Pinker) in his [*The Better Angels of Our Nature*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Better_Angels_of_Our_Nature) and [Hans Rosling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Rosling) in his Ted Talk [The best stats you've ever seen (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVimVzgtD6w).